# informatica mapping to count the no.of employees in each organisation

Tags: mapping, informatica, informatica-powercenter

can anyone tell me how to create mapping for the following scenario:

```
Source:                 Target:
emp_id  org             EMP_COUNT  ORG
1         x                2         X
2         Y                2         Y
3         X                1         z
4         Y
5         Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an aggregator transformation with ORG as group by port. For EMP_COUNT, create an output port in the aggregator with the expression: COUNT(emp_id).

Answer (score -1):

create a source based on which source you going to use like oracle,flat file,etc
connect source to target with expression transformation in between where you can do all the functions , you can also create a new column i.e. port and do the calculations.